# How do I sort the result of an SQL join by a single column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, list, grouping, unordered

I have a database with a list of locations e.g.:

```
C_ID   |   Name 

1      |   Italy
2      |   Germany
3      |   France
4      |   Spain
```

and in a seperate table, a list of people who are from those countries,

```
P_ID  |  Name   |  C_ID

1     | John    | 1
2     | Mark    | 1
3     | Paul    | 2
4     | Pierre  | 3
5     | Alan    | 2
```

I have grabbed this data in an SQL query with a join...

```
SELECT locations.name as locaname, people.name as peoplename
FROM locations
INNER JOIN people
ON locations.c_id=people.c_id
ORDER BY locations.name";
```

Which provides me with:

```
Italy John
Italy Mark
Germany Paul
Germany Alan
France Pierre
```

However, what I am trying to achieve is a unordered list, echoed out by PHP. With the people names **grouped by country name**. As opposed to the country name being repeated. I've tried using arrays however my knowledge of PHP/MySQL is letting me down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql = <<<END
SELECT locations.name as locaname, people.name as peoplename
FROM locations
INNER JOIN people
ON locations.c_id=people.c_id
ORDER BY locations.name"
END;
$query = mysql_query($query) or die($sql . ' - ' . mysql_error());
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $result[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

`$row[0]` is the country, `$row[1]` is the person's name. The function in the `while` loop is key here. This does quite a lot. It basically adds an entry to the result array keyed by country name and appends the person's name to the array it stores there.

**Edit:** To order as a list:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($result as $country => $persons) {
  echo "<li>$country\n<ul>\n";
  foreach ($persons as $person) {
    echo "<li>$person</li>\n";
  }
  echo "</ul></li>\n";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: yes this groups the join exactly as I need, thanks muchly. 
How is it possible to order this as a list now? i.e. <ul><li> style
Sorry for being such a noob at this...

Comment: The added code only provides one child for each parent, not the correct number of children..